# Redirect when authentication timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, model-view-controller

So i would like my application to redirect automatically to the login page, once the authentication timeout.
I am using mvc core, and when the user login I am setting up an authentication cookie

```
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                //options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.LoginPath = "/Authentication";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Authentication";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Authentication/Denied";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
                options.SlidingExpiration = false;
            });
```

Coupled with the Authorize attribute, when the timeout has been reached i am being redirected to the login page **IF** i click on an element that has the attribute.

What i would like is to be redirected automatically as well, for example if i have been on a form and idle for too long then be redirected, and not wait for the user to click at the right place.

I have read few posts that talks about sessions timeout, but I haven't found anything that explains the difference between the session cookie, and the authentication cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to write a middleware function that checks for auth token before completing the request would be a quick and clean way to take care of this.

Before any request can be completed, write an 'isAuthenticated' function that either. The alternative is to constantly track the time left before the token runs out, and that would be inefficient compared to a middleware function for each request.

Comment: I think i agree with you, but this is already the behaviour, all my forms call a method on a controller that have an Authorize attribute, so i will be redirected on click to the login page.
I was hoping maybe for somekind of event that can be triggered or something of the like